PlantUML Activity Diagrams: Why don't my activities align vertically in the right-hand swimlane
I have a flow passing back and forth between two swimlanes. All the logic is in the left one, in the right swimlane are a series of activities. I expect each activity to align vertically but there are unexpected horizontal offsets. I get the same results whether I run it locally in Eclipse or on the PlantUML server.

This is my code:
@startuml
title: Test
|Swimlane1|
|#LightGreen|Swimlane2|
|Swimlane1|
:Do A; 
|Swimlane2|
:Do B;
|Swimlane1|
:Do C;
|Swimlane2|
:Do D;
|Swimlane1|
:Do E;
if (Test1?) then (  <b>yes</b>)
|Swimlane2|
:Do F;
|Swimlane1|
:Do G;
else (  <b>no</b>)
:


;
|Swimlane2|
:Do H;
|Swimlane1|
:Do I;
if (Test2?) then (  <b>no</b>)
:Do J;
else (  <b>yes</b>)
if (Test3?) then (  <b>yes</b>)
:Do K;
else (  <b>no</b>)
:Do L";
|Swimlane2|
:Do M;
:Do N;
|Swimlane1|
:Do O; 
endif
endif
endif
:Do P;
stop
@enduml

I expected Do B, Do D, Do F, Do H, Do M, Do N all to be aligned vertically in the middle of the swimlane.
As you can imagine, with real labels this makes swimlane2 very wide.
Please note that I had to put a dummy empty activity at lines 21-24 to resolve a problem of crossing lines.

I assume this is a bug (feature?) due to the width of the left swim-lane. That is, the nesting of if/then causes the width of the left swim-lane to grow, and it appears also to force new columns in the activities of the right swim-lane. This is a question to ask on the PlantUML Q&A forum at plantuml.net

I don't think that's the issue. I played about and found that the width of the 2nd swimlane is entirely dependent on the number of flows I have coming into it. Two separate flows are never placed one above each other in the same vertical alignment, they are always offset by the width of the activities in the flow. Only activities in the same flow are placed one above each other. Further, I created a third swimlane, and that exhibited the exact same behaviour.

I think we're saying the same thing (the width is a result of separate flows).
